# fastify-mongodb : "mongo" is undefined when accessed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, fastify

I'm attempting to use Fastify and fastify-monogdb.
Currently I have the following...

In my **/src/index.js**

```js
const routes = require("./routes");
const fastify = require("fastify")({
  logger: true
});

routes.forEach((route, index) => {
  fastify.route(route);
});

fastify.register(require("fastify-mongodb"), {
  url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/parkedcars"
});

const startFastify = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen(3333);
    fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`);
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

startFastify();
```

In my **/routes/index.js** I have a route...

```js
const carController = require("../controllers/carController");

  {
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/create/parkedcar",
    handler: carController.createParkedCar
  }
```

And finally in my **/controllers/carController**...

```js
const fastify = require("fastify")();

  exports.createParkedCar = async (req, reply) => {
  try {
    let car = { ...req.body };
    const db = fastify.mongo.db
    *// will do insert here*
    return car;
  } catch (err) {
    throw boom.boomify(err);
  }
};
```

When I attempt to call:
**const db = fastify.mongo.db**

I get an error that says...
**"Cannot read property 'db' of undefined"**

What am I doing wrong here?
How is **mongo** undefined at this point?
Doesn't "fastify.register" make this accessible to me?

Comment: You don't need to require fastify in the carController. Use this.mongo in the controller See this example https://github.com/fastify/fastify-mongodb#usage also if you require fastify the way you do it in the controller you are creating new instance of fastify.

Comment: Tried that.  Still the same error.
Using "this" works in the "/src/index.js".  

Also using "fastify.mongo.db" works in the "/src/index.js"  

How does "this" refer to fastify when accessed from a different JS file?

Comment: "this" refers to fastify because, although i haven't checked, the handlers are called with fastify context. `...handler.call(fastify, request, reply)` The only reason you get the same error i can think of is that the order of adding fastify.register matters(as it does in Express.js) so try to move `routes.forEach...` bellow the code `fastify.register(require("fastify-mongodb")...`

Comment: I think I just found the issue.  By putting the routes in a separate file as I have done, you do not have access to the Fastify instance.    
See this:  https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/392

Comment: By the way, they suggest some ways to handle it here:  https://github.com/fastify/fastify-mongodb/issues/9

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the `require("fastify")()` **only** in your once per application because it is a factory and not a singleton, so every time you run the require you are creating a brand new HTTP server!

The magic is to use the `.register` in a proper way and/or using `function` instead of arrow function in the handler.

For your use case you could change the carController:

```
  exports.createParkedCar = function handler (req, reply) {
    let car = { ...req.body };
    const db = this.mongo.db
    *// will do insert here*
    db.insert(...)
      .then(() => reply.send(car))
      .catch((err) => reply.send(boom.boomify(err)))
  }
```

because all the function handlers, in fastify, are bound to the fastify server instance (like this `aFunction.bind(fastify)`). The arrow functions can't be binded.

Another options is to use the register:

```
// /routes/index.js

module.exports = (fastify, opts, next) => {

  fastify.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/create/parkedcar",
    handler: async (req, reply) => {
      try {
        let car = { ...req.body };
        const db = fastify.mongo.db
        *// will do insert here*
        return car;
      } catch (err) {
        throw boom.boomify(err);
      }
  });

  next() // dont forget it
}
```

For more info checkout [the docs](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Plugins.md#create-a-plugin)